# Overwrite instance method defined with #define_singleton_method and call original

Tags: ruby

I have a class that defines methods dynamically on its instances like this

```
obj = Object.new
obj.define_singleton_method(:foo) { "foo" }
```

On a later point, I'd like to redefine the `#foo`, but be able to call the original implementation(s).

When using normal classes, this can be achieved with `prepend MyModule` and calling `super` inside the prepended methods. But `#prepend` is not available on an instance level.

I tried it with `#extend` but it seems like it does not overwrite the `#foo` method at all:

```
obj = Object.new
obj.define_singleton_method(:foo) { "foo" }
mod = Module.new
mod.define_method(:foo) { "module foo" }
obj.extend(mod)
obj.foo
# => "foo"
```

I had a look into the RSpec gem, because they implement a similar behaviour with `#and_wrap_original` (see https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/3-8/docs/configuring-responses/wrapping-the-original-implementation) **but I'm not in an test environment**, and it looks like a lot of setup code to achieve this behaviour (keeping track of stubs, having callbacks when to reset them etc.).

So any idea how to do this in pure Ruby?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at `obj.singleton_class.ancestors` to see what actually happens. By default, it is something like

```
[#<Class:#<Object:0x00007febcf103160>>, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]
```

If you do `obj.extend(mod)`, you will get this:

```
[#<Class:#<Object:0x00007febcf103160>>, #<Module:0x00007febcd0bb088>, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]
```

So the order is bad, because the module comes "behind" the singleton class. In order to replace it, it needs to be earlier in the ancestor chain. You can do this by `obj.singleton_class.prepend(mod)`. The ancestor chain in that case is:

```
[#<Module:0x00007febcd0bb088>, #<Class:#<Object:0x00007febcf103160>>, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]
```

and the output shows that the method is overridden:

```
obj.foo
# => "module foo"
```